# Is it possible to "extend" the cursor crosshairs in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to draw a marquee around an image so I can cut it out, but it's near-impossible to accurately get the first corner aligned properly with the boundaries of the area I'm trying to select.

If the crosshairs of the marquee tool extended to the edge of the screen, it would be easy to see if the box I'm about to draw is going to contain the area I need to select.

Comment: Approximate the upper left selection corner (doesn't need to be exact), select exactly what you need for lower and right borders, deselect, then start a new selection using the now proper lower and right borders, and select proper upper and left borders based on the selection border.

Comment: You could try using guides to help you align things.